# Using Date offset in CAML query

Tags: caml-query

In SharePoint 2010, Inned to get items from a list based on a condition. Considering one of the fields to be 'EventDate' of type DateTime, the condition is:

```
(EventDate - 60 Days) <= Today <= (EventDate + 30Days).
```

Note that the values 60 and 30 are not static.

To rephrase it in words, I need to show the list item if the event occurs 60 days from today or has occurred 30 days from today.

Hence, I need  a rolling window on the EventDate. The OffsetDate attribute on Today element in CAML provides a rolling window on the Current date. Is it possible to achieve this in CAML? If not how do I filter the list items based on this condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the query that worked:

```
    <Where>
      <And>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>
               <Today Offset='-30' />
            </Value>
         </Geq>
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>
               <Today Offset='60' />
            </Value>
         </Leq>
      </And>
   </Where>
```

It was only a small change i.e. to subtract the EndDate and add the StartDate to the current date.Thank you @PirateEric for your help.

Comment: Didn't work for me util I changed to <Today OffsetDays='-30' />

Comment: Also for me it did not work, had to use `OffsetDays` as Jaime Arroyo Garcia.

Comment: Thanks Suhas it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 14):

You'd use something like this, using the [BIWUG CamlDesigner](http://sharepoint.biwug.be/Pages/Downloads.aspx):

```
       <Where>
      <Or>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='StartDate' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>
               <Today OffsetDays='30' />
            </Value>
         </Geq>
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='StartDate' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>
               <Today OffsetDays='-60' />
            </Value>
         </Leq>
      </Or>
   </Where>
```

Comment: I assume you should change "Geq" to "Leq", and then "Eq" to "Geq" :)

Comment: CAML output wasn't updating, that should do it. greater than or equal today + 30 and less than or equal to today - 60.

Comment: the above query will not give the correct result. Let me give an example:
If the StartDate is 2-Jun, then the date ranges are 2-Apr( 2/Jun - 60) and 2-Jul(2/Jun + 30)
[for the sake of brevity I am considering 30 day months]. Hence if the condition 2-Apr <= current date <= 2-Jul satisfies then the list item should be obtained. Hence, on 3-jul this list item should not be obtained.
If we apply the above query with current date as 3-Jul, then the date ranges are:
3-May (3/Jul - 60) to 3-Aug (3/Jul + 30) and 2-jun lies between the date ranges. Hence on 3-Jul this list item will be obtained.

Comment: his happens because the offset applies to the current date and not the StartDate (i.e. list field).

Comment: That's the only way I know it can be done, based on evaluating the current date. Are you trying to pass in a value as a filter to something that dynamically?

Comment: yes...I found a workaround by adding extra columns.

Comment: Instead of Offset use OffsetDays

Comment: @nbi thanks for bringing that to my attention, I've updated the answer to be up to snuff, hope that changes your mind on the down vote. Alternatively, you can propose an edit to the question in the future.

Comment: @EricAlexander Upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

Update for SharePoint 2013: although MSDN lists Offset as an attribute for Today element (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms460496.aspx), when customizing the CAML on a list view in SharePoint Designer 2013 I tried the Offset attribute but it didn't work. I used the "`OffsetDays`" attribute (not documented in MSDN) and the query returned the desired output (items with date field up to 5 days from the current date).

Answer (score 4):

Marked answer won't work (at least in SP 2010) unless you change the Today Offset bit to "Today OffsetDays" thus having:

```
<Where>
  <And>
     <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
        <Value Type='DateTime'>
           <Today OffsetDays='-30' />
        </Value>
     </Geq>
     <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
        <Value Type='DateTime'>
           <Today OffsetDays='60' />
        </Value>
     </Leq>
  </And>
```

Cheers!