# Create CAML query with have a value field with SharePoint column-SharePoint 2010

Tags: caml-query

I have a SharePoint list. It has two columns Start date and End date. I need to query and get data if (start date + 7 days> End date). Through CAML builder its not possible to have a SharePoint column on value node and build the query. Any idea? I have tried below. But not working.

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
         <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'><StartDate+7/></Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is similar to a question asked earlier here.

You can use **Offset**

Please check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37779/using-date-offset-in-caml-query) link.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Comment: I need to have a column in the value field which is not in the FieldRef in CAML.

Comment: are you using server object model or client object model?

Comment: Server object model.