# Retrieve List items using CAML Query

Tags: 2010, 2013, list, caml-query, caml

- I have a list which contains 3 columns -ID, TicketState and EndDate

  ```
  ID        TicketState           EndDate(DD-MM-YYYY)

  1             Open            10/10/2012
  2            Closed           01/12/2012 
  3           Discard           05/05/2011
  4             Open            28/05/2013
  5           Discard           10/11/2012

  So, I want to retrieve those items whose TicketState is Either 
  Closed OR Discard, 
  AND
  EndDate < 1 year (from todays Date)
  ```

For that i have written following CAML Query but it is not working....

```
SPQuery myquery = new SPQuery();
    myquery.Query = "<Where>" +
                       "<And>" +
                           "<Or>" +
                              "<Eq><FieldRef Name='TicketState' /><Value Type='Choice'>Closed</Value></Eq>" +
                              "<Eq><FieldRef Name='TicketState' /><Value Type='Choice'>Discard</Value></Eq>" +      
                           "</Or>" +
                         "<Geq><FieldRef Name='End_x0020_Time' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'><Today Offset='-365' /></Value></Geq>" +
                       "</And>" +
                    "</Where>";
```

**EDIT:**

Solved. Problem was with the internal name.

Comment: Is the field name "End%5Fx0020%5FTime" correct ?

Comment: i have edited..check it out

Comment: What's the output your getting. In your sample list there seems to be no date ranging within one year. Are you getting any output ?

Comment: No Output....i think problem with caml query itself..

Comment: Solved...Problem was with the internal name.... Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Solved...Problem was with the internal name....

Thank you..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `<Eq>` with `End_x0020_Time` column, instead you should be using `<Geq>` or `<Leq>` as per your need..

Please have a look at:

[Using Date offset in CAML query](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37779/using-date-offset-in-caml-query)

Comment: used <Geq>..still no output and i hav data ranging within the dates

Comment: If you want 1 year difference, why are you giving -100 as Offset. You should be giving -365 as Offset, isn't it ?

Comment: If you are working only on the data that you have mentioned in the post you wont get any results. Is there any other relevant data. Are you using the CAML U2U builder ? If yes, are you getting any results in the tool ?

Comment: Offset= -365 done, still no output